# ScrollTo target:_parent not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, scrollto

I have an iframe inside a parent web (with jquery) which has a link to go up in the parent web

```
<a href="javascript:$.scrollTo(100,800);" target="_parent">Go Up</a>
```

it works in safari and explorer but not in chrome... 
any suggestions tu make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
<a href="javascript:parent.$.scrollTo(100,800);" target="_parent" >Go Up</a>
```

Comment: BTW : if testing cross-frame manipulation in chrome, you need to test in a server, it won't work locally ... of course, within the same domain.